# PDF flattening in Windows

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, printing

I have a PDF document which I generated from R/ggplot2. It includes several plots that have "alpha" or transparency specifications. The PDF file renders happily to a variety of PDF readers, but in Windows and when I attempt to print, PDF attempts to "flatten" the images. This goes on for a while, and eventually(1+ hour for a 30 page document) I have to abort.

This problem has been reported before without a clear resolution. ([Flatten the alpha channel in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849351/flatten-the-alpha-channel-in-ggplot2#27517463)) When I try this solution, R/Bookdown complains that I am trying to sneak HTML elements (the PNG I suspect) into the PDF.

Is there a way to post-process the  R/ggplot2 PDF output so that when I do try to print the PDF, it will work?

Although I eventually distribute a PDF which can print in Windows environments, I can move the PDF from Windows to Linux, "fix" the PDF there, and the re-port the file back to Windows for printing,... if only there are relevant linux tools. OSX available too.

Suggestions? Hard to produce a reproducible example of a print spooling problem.

Answer (score 1):

Started this as a comment to Maurits Evers answer above, but it got too big for a comment.

Doing that (PDF->PS->PDF) will generally (for a transparent PDF file) end up with a bitmap image wrapped up in a PDF file. Which loses quality, isn't readily scalable, etc.

If the PDF file doesn't contain genuine transparency (eg Cairo-produced PDF where all the transparency is 100% opaque) then you could use Ghostscript's pdfwrite and the -dNOTRANSPARENCY flag to produce a new PDF file where all the transparency has been removed.

If you want to preserve it, then the only solution is to render the transparent areas. However, I'd suggest setting CompatibilityLevel to 1.3 and using the pdfwrite device, rather than the double-conversion via PostScript. Going to PostScript will simply dump a load of other stuff in the process, which is less likely to happen going to PDF.

There is also a new device (which will be in the next release) called pdfimage which simply renders the pages to bitmap images, and then write a PDF file where each page is an image.

Comment: Thanks to you both. I will try the ghostscript approach today. Ken - is the pdfimage utility you mention in the next release of ghostscript?

Comment: It'll be in the next release, yes (March, version 9.23 probably). You can get it now but it means cloning our Git repository and building it yourself, which is tedious.

Comment: @KenS Very interesting and useful, thanks for the details.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com)'s `pdf2ps` and `ps2pdf`:

1. Convert PDF to a PS

   ```
   pdf2ps source.pdf source.ps
   ```
2. Convert PS to a flattened PDF

   ```
   ps2pdf source.ps source_flattened.pdf
   ```

This should/will work on all systems *nix and Windows (you might have to install Ghostscript).

I've also found [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162922/is-there-a-way-to-flatten-a-pdf-image-from-the-command-line) that gives additional details and alternative methods.